# Retain Focus on Reloading Html Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create several pages which have the same **accordion** side menu. My issue is that whenever I access one page from another, I lose the **focus** of the side menu element that I've clicked.

I know that this is due to the fact that the **DOM** reloads in the browser whenever I change the page and renders the elements from the start.

[image]

My file structure goes like this:

> main.html (root file)
>  |
>  |
>  Pages (sub-folder)
>  |
>   |
>  pageOne.html _ _ _ _ pageTwo.html

Is there a way to achieve this purely with **jQuery** or by using **Bootstrap** ?

> How can I retain focus on sub-menu items such as **item 2** and main
>   menu items whenever I access different pages?

Comment: you can use `localstorage` to store the current focused item and then on the load of your new page get that item and call the `$('item').focus();`

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Here in your case since the page is reloading, the browser cannot remember the selection (though there are ways which I wouldn't want to recommend like storing the selected menu in local storage or somewhere and later on page load read that value and use it), server though has the information. So while rendering the page and the menu you can pass this information to your accordion and render with the appropriate element selected.

Comment: can you throw a simple JsFiddle by any chance?

Comment: I am currently reworking the whole application using AngularJs. I've decided that it would take me less time to remake it with `ng-include` and `ng-show` rather than trial and error with local storage. Thank you for your assistance in the first place.

Comment: Cool, that completely changes the question then. So is your page still reloading?

Comment: no, the side menu is made static and all the rest of the content is loaded dynamically thus preventing from refreshing the menu itself.

Comment: and does the page reload?

Comment: well it doesn't